# Chaining user conversions in c++

Tags: c++

Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct C
{
    C() 
    {   
        std::cout << "C()\n";
    }   

    explicit C(const C&) 
    {   
        std::cout << "C(const C&)\n";
    }   

    operator int()
    {   
        std::cout << "int()\n";
        return 1;
    }   

    C(int)
    {   
        std::cout << "C(int)\n";
    }   
};

int main()
{
    C c1; 
    std::cout << '\n';
    C c2 = c1; 
    std::cout << '\n';
    C c3(c1);
}
```

Both `g++` and `clang` give the following output:

```
C()

int()
C(int)

C(const C&)
```

Doesn't it break the rule saying that an implicit conversion sequence can consist of at most one user conversion?

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: I could be wrong, but `C(int)` takes an `int`. `C -> int` is one user-defined conversion. I don't see why `int->C` would be included in that sequence. It's rather like doing `std::string s(someObjectWithACstrConversion);`. The function you're calling just happens to be something that can be used as a conversion elsewhere.

Comment: @sehe I would expect a compiler error.

Comment: Where and why. Always state your expectations. Otherwise, it's hard to debug your expectations/explain

Comment: I think that `C c2 = c1;` should produce an error because two user conversions are called.

Comment: Ah, so because the copy constructor is explicit, the line `C c2 = c1` will not invoke the copy constructor. Instead, the compiler realizes that there exists a non-explicit constructor `C(int)` and conveniently an implicit conversion from `C` to `int`. So what is happening is that the conversion from `c1` to `int` happens, followed by invocation of the `C(int)` constructor.

Comment: I only see one conversion happening. That is, `C` --> `int`. The compiler then selects the appropriate constructor based on that conversion. What is the other conversion you are thinking of? If you want to cause two conversions to be necessary, clang will give an error: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5220236d22af651

Comment: @AndyG https://ideone.com/o55VbG

Comment: @piotrekg2: I'm not sure what that's supposed to be showing me. `C c2 = c1` is construction, so a constructor should be called, and `C(int)` is the best candidate. The only implicit conversion happening is from `c1` to an `int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This only compiles because you're initializing class `C` with itself in the line `C c2 = c1;`. If you had a class `D` which behaves identically to `C` and tried `D d; C c = d;`, it wouldn't compile for the reason you stated: because the implicit conversion would require two user-defined conversions. [Demonstation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14843362367e36fb)

The reason it compiles when using the same class is that copy-initialization (`A x = y;`) behaves differently when `y` is of type `A` or derived from it. In that case, a converting constructor is selected and that constructor is then invoked with the argument `y`, which may cause an implicit conversion. The constructor call itself is not part of the implicit conversion.

So in your code, the conversion sequence only contains one user-defined conversion: `C` to `int`, as the constructor `C(int)` is called separately.

See C++14 8.5/17:

> - If the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualiﬁed
>     version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination,
>     constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated (13.3.1.3), and the best
>     one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3). The constructor so selected is called to initialize
>     the object, with the initializer expression or expression-list as its argument(s).
> - Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-deﬁned conversion sequences
>     that can convert from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function
>     is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated [...]

Read more at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization.